# Precedence order of function execution in C

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence

What is the execution sequence of the following statement:

```
x = f(2) * g(5) + h();
```

I have seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) link, the precedence order should be f, g and h.
Am I right or not, please explain

Comment: This is a syntax error, you are missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: @JakubZaverka This is just an expression, please ignore compilation error. Assume that the functions exists. By mistake I added a parenthesis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you can't make any guarantees about the order of execution of the functions.

While precedence rules imply that `f(2)` will be multiplied by `g(5)` before `h()` is added to the result, the order of execution of these sub-expressions is implementation-defined.

If you're doing this with functions that have side-effects, don't. Depending on the code, you may or may not see different results from compiler to compiler.

**Note:** As @Jakub Zaverka mentions, there are slightly different rules when you're dealing with logical operators `&&` or `||` because of features like short-circuiting.

Comment: What if those were OR and AND operatots?

Comment: @JakubZaverka In that case, you _can_ make certain guarantees about the order of execution because of things like short-circuiting. In, `f() || g()`, `g()` will never execute before `f()` is complete.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. What if the statement is this `x = (f(2) * g(5)) + h();`

Comment: @JackDaniels Same thing. The functions could execute in any order, but ultimately, the precedence of the operations on the results of those functions will be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

With `x = f(2) * g(5) + h();`
`f(2)`, `g(5)` and `h()` are executed in *any* sequence - perhaps even simultaneous if the processor supports such.

The results of `f()` and `g()` are multiplied.  That product is then added to the result of `h()`.